# C# winsta0/winlogon not going topmost when locking in winsta0/custom

Tags: c#, windows-10, uac, winlogon

We have a service to manage some custom desktops using the user32.dll `SetThreadDesktop` and `SwitchDesktop` methods. Everything has been working well until Windows 10 version 1709 arrived.

With this Windows 10 version (or later), when `EnableLUA` is activated (when we have a custom desktop active), if the user locks his session, the winlogon desktop doesn’t appear and our custom desktop remains visible (though it isn’t possible to interact with it) until the user presses the combination CTRL+ALT+DEL.

It seems like the winlogon desktop is not able to stay topmost over our custom desktop. I didn't find any information about this, so is this a possibility? Could anything else be going on?

PD: Same scenario on Windows 10 version 1607 device works well.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recognized the bug and they will solve it. The error is reproducible with the Sysinternals Desktops tool (currently belonging to Microsoft).

Waiting for an update that fix it...